# ASP MVC Identity 2 get user in "User" role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I add user and assign role as below code, I user ASP MVC 5 identity and EF code first.

```
//some Code
                var result = manager.Create(insert, applicationUser.PasswordHash);
                IdentityResult result2 =null;
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                result2 = manager.AddToRole(insert.Id, "User");
}
//Some Code
```

So i need to show list of user with custom role in view like "User" role. i wrote this code :

```
    ApplicationDbContext myDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var getRoleId = myDbContext.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "User").Select(m => m.Id).SingleOrDefault();
    var fetch = myDbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId.ToString() == getRoleId)).ToList();
    return View(fetch);
```

`getRoleId` value is "4", it is right , but `fetch` always count equal 0.I try more than 3 4 hours but i can not get result.Where is my wrong ? and what is the solution ?
Thank you.

**UPDATE :**
I found my problem in add role but i do not know how can fix that !
When adding the users to roles using the above, the users id is added to the UserId column of the UserRoles table, but there was a third column called IdentityUser_Id which was always null.

Out of curiosity I added my user id to that column as well and now the everything works. the application picked up my user role.

My follow up question to this is can I set the IdentityUser_Id automatically? using something similar to the UserManager.AddToRole() which adds the userId to both columns?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you getting getRowId and not pull Users by Role Name? Try Below:

```
  var fetch = myDbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == 
     "User")).ToList();
```

Comment: u.Roles dose not have Name Properties.just have r.RoleId and r.UserId !

Comment: Have you created a custom Role class and add as a property in User Class?

Comment: No, I use ASP MVC identity system

Comment: i get all user list whit this code var `fetch2 = myDbContext.Users.Select(u => u.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId =="4")).ToList();` but i just have 5 user that have "User" Role !